# A probability problem involving license plates

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Here is the problem.

> If car number plates in a country have three letters followed by
>   a 3 digit number, what is the probability that a number plate:

is XYZ 123?

Comment: Without further information one would have to assume that all $26^3\times 10^3$ cases are equally likely. Then the probability for a particular number would be $1/(26^3\times 10^3)$. But this is not reality. There can be patterns in the letters and restrictions on the numbers.

Comment: For an arbitrary plate, how many choices are there for the first letter? Start there.

Comment: The total number of  car numbers are $26^3.10^3$.  This is the denominator and figure out what is the numerator for just one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of each character appearing is independent of each other, so we can just multiply their probabilities together.

Ans = $\big(\frac{1}{26}\big)^3 \times \big(\frac{1}{10}\big)^3$

Comment: I understand everything else but, why are we raising 1 to the third power?

Comment: because there are 3 letters and 3 numbers

Comment: @BlakeJacobs you aren't raising $1$ to the third power.  The way JTg wrote this was ambiguous.  You are raising $(\frac{1}{26})$ to the third power.  This is because for independent events, the probability of all events happening simultaneously is the product of their respective probabilities.  Here the events are "First letter is an X", "Second letter is a Y",... "Sixth number is a 3" with corresponding probabilities $\frac{1}{26},\frac{1}{26},\dots,\frac{1}{10}$, giving the final probability $\frac{1}{26}\cdot\frac{1}{26}\cdots\frac{1}{10}=(\frac{1}{26})^3(\frac{1}{10})^3$

Comment: Oh, I see now, This was actually quite simple I should have probably spent more time on the problem. Thanks, J Tg and JMoravitze.

Comment: I will accept J Tg's answer anyway.